# REST API access always returns invalid access when requesting Access Token

Tags: rest-api, c#

I am developing a C# console application that needs to connect to my company's Salesforce sandbox via the API to pull data.  After some searching, I am using the nuget package [DeveloperForce.Force](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeveloperForce.Force/) to help with the connection.

I'm trying to use the [OAuth username/password](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm&language=en_US) method to get my Access Token without success.

Here is the sample code taken from the Nuget Package project site that I am trying.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            var task = RunSample();
            task.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            var innerException = e.InnerException;
            while (innerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(innerException.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(innerException.StackTrace);
                innerException = innerException.InnerException;
            }
        }
    }

    private static async Task RunSample()
    {
        var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
         // Authenticate with Salesforce
        Console.WriteLine("Authenticating with Salesforce");
        var url = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";


        await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync("VALID_CLIENT_ID", "VALID_CLIENT_SECRET", "VALID_SALESFORCE_USER", "VALID_SALESFORCE_PASSWORD_AND_SECURITY_TOKEN, url);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Salesforce");
        var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);
        // retrieve all accounts
       Console.WriteLine("Get Accounts");
       const string qry = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Account";
       var accts = new List<Account>();
       var results = await client.QueryAsync<Account>(qry);
       var totalSize = results.totalSize;
       Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " records.");
    }
}
```

Inside the [Nuget package code](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/master/src/CommonLibrariesForNET/AuthenticationClient.cs), the request is being made on line 68 with the correct values.
However, this request is returning a 400 error saying that the password is invalid.  (I have verified all the values are correct and gotten a colleague to confirm this).

In Salesforce I have done the following in hopes to resolve this

- Enabled my `Connected App`  to my custom community
- Created a new `Permission Set` and linked my `Connected App` to the user directly

The `Connected App` has the following scopes (likely overkill, but just trying to get it to work)

- Access and manage your data (api)
- Full access (full)
- Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
- Provide access to custom applications (visualforce)
- Provide access to your data via the Web (web)

At this point, I'm thinking there is another setting within Salesforce that I have to set, but I cannot seem to find it.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm that the user has the API Enabled permission on their profile? Also, what scopes are you using in your connected app?

Comment: @MarkMasterson - How can I check if the user has API Enabled permission?

Comment: 1. Check API Enabled Permision: Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > [Profile of the user in question] > Administrative Permission > API Enabled

Comment: Or if you have Enhanced Profile User Interface enabled: Setup > Manage Users > Profiles > [Profile of the user in question] > System Permissions > API Enabled

Comment: @MarkMasterson - The profile is System Administrator.  It appears the API Enabled is set up

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem like anything in your configuration is wrong then. Connected App has full OAuth scope, user is assigned the connected app through permission set, and user API enabled. I would recommend trying to reset your security token and trying a new one as a next step.

Comment: @MarkMasterson - that seemed to do the trick, although I'm not sure why as I tried that on Friday with no luck.  If you make that an answer, I will accept it - thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of the configuration settings on the Connected App, nothing seemed out of place:

1. User was assigned the Connected App through a permission set.
2. Consumer Key and Consumer secret were correct (as confirmed by you and a colleague).
3. Connected App OAuth scopes are correct.
4. User is API Enabled.

My recommended next step after checking these configurations was to try a security token refresh, and that seems to have done the trick. I wish I had a better explanation than sometimes Salesforce seems to be finicky with the security token, but it works often enough for me to be a sort of "Turn it off, and turn it on again"-type solution in my own troubleshooting steps. Perhaps someone else has better insight into the why of this.